# ImportError: cannot import name 'ImageTK'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, python-import

I cannot seem to figure out how to fix a problem with my code regarding `import ImageTK` from PIL. I have searched and downloaded Pillow different ways and the error of the code is still the same.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "8_Age_Calculator_App.py", line 3, in <module>
  from PIL import Image, ImageTK
ImportError: cannot import name 'ImageTK'
```

These are the import codes of the file

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageTK
import tkinter as tk
import datetime
```

and this is the code that is trying to import the image

```
main_image = Image.open('/Users/Brenden/Documents/Python_OOP/old-people-
running-illo_h.jpg')
main_image.thumbnail((100,100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
main_photo = ImageTK.Photoimage(main_image)
main_label_image = tk.Label(image=main_photo)
main_label.grid(column=1, row=0)
```

How may I fix this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a typo in the module you want to import. The `k` in `ImageTk` should be lower case:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

this should solve your problem

and in your script you have another case typo, `PhotoImage` is CamelCase:

```
main_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(main_image)
```

Comment: No problem! If you use an IDE like PyCharm (which is for free for private use) you can get around most of the problems because it informs you about such errors.

Comment: Okay! I'm using sublime text 3 as the text editor and Gitbash to run the code. I was told Pycharm is for those who more familiar with coding. So I guess once I've gotten the hang of things I'll switch over to it! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 32):

Use this command for Python 3

```
 sudo apt-get install python3-pil.imagetk
```

Comment: This worked well on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS! Thanks +1.

Answer (score 2):

Install it using this command.

```
sudo apt-get install python-imaging-tk
```

Answer (score 2):

ImageT**K** is k(small letter) not K (capital letter)

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

Answer (score 1):

To install for python2 type in terminal:

 `sudo apt-get install python-pil.imagetk`


For python3 type:

 `sudo apt-get install python3-pil.imagetk`


To import Image and ImageTk:

`from PIL import Image, ImageTk`


There's a typo in your script, it will be `PhotoImage`:

`main_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(main_image)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to write this command in the terminal:

```
pip install pillow
```

It will install PIL packages